# Начать отправлять (чей-то) культ - можно?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Так храм Вознесения Господня превратится в центр поклонения Савве,
>   станет местом великого паломничества. Святой был настолько почитаем
>   сербами, что вскоре и местное турецкое население (после завоевания
>   территорий в 1459 году) начало отправлять его культ.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он затрагивает не проблему Русского языка, а проблему автора.

Comment: @shampar А ведь не так давно я к Вам относилась как к вменяемой особи. Ошибку учту.

Comment: Автора редактируемого Вами текста я имел в виду. Или Вы цитируете свой?

Comment: О, у автора никаких проблем, он думает, что всё в порядке. Это у меня проблемы с русским языком, этим и рождён вопрос.

Comment: Ваш вопрос рождён последними тремя словами, как я понимаю. Автор текста демонстрирует, что не в курсе кому поклоняются христиане, а кого они почитают, так зачем же вывешивать это его недоразумение здесь и давать первую часть цитаты? Есть в этом смысл?

Comment: По поводу избыточности цитаты: у меня часто просили дать расширенный контекст.

Comment: «Горбатый», извините, контекст не несёт пользы никому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправлять его культ- вполне приемлемая фраза. Отправлять культ - совершать какие-то действия, символизирующие поклонение божеству. Чтобы назвать имя божества, нужно задать вопросы *культ кого ? чей культ?*

Например, *культ Аполлона*. Аполлона (кого? чей?)-несогласованное определение, согласованное - *Аполлонов* культ (какой? чей?) Заменим имя притяжательным местоимением - **его культ**. ***Культ Аполлона, Аполлонов***, ***его*** - вполне заменяются, так что сочетание ***его культ***  имеет полное право на жизнь.

Answer (score 1):

"После того как мужчины **стали отправлять культ** бок о бок с женщинами, предаваясь разврату под покровом темноты, начали твориться безобразия и преступления" (Джон Бэлсдон).

"...ушли, но, как видимо не надолго, поскольку в другой зале они тут же **начали отправлять** другой **культ** и зазывать на зрелище кого-то верховного" (Александр Олейников).

[Отправлять](https://znachenie-slova.ru/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) (Т. Ф. Ефремова)

2. несов. перех. устар.
   2) Выполнять, совершать (какое-л. действие, обряд и т. п.).

(Извините — в комментарии "не уместилось".)
"Он выступил против жречества Амона, против людей, уполномоченных [отправлять его культ](https://books.google.ee/books?id=MriPAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%20%D0%B6%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0,%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9,%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85.%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82&source=bl&ots=LGjS_WBu6M&sig=ACfU3U33T2lN7MDQ6MJ7Ix_VsHTz-x0yjQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3ooa9vL_jAhXJ6aQKHY1CAsYQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%20%D0%B6%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%2C%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85.%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82&f=false), против священнослужителей, с его точки зрения, совершенно недостойных своей задачи" (А. Э. Ермановская. Загадки истории. Древний мир).

Comment: Я подозревала, что ***отправлять культ*** можно, и любым составом, но вопрос о: *отправлять **его** культ.*