# "Не надолго" — слитно или раздельно? "Как видимо" — запятые (одно предложение)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частица-не, вводные-слова, род

Когда отвечала на вопрос участника Галины Аванесовой (Можно ли начать отправлять (его) [культ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453605/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE)?), попалось вот такое предложение.

"Многое приходило мне на ум, но тут вдруг все жрецы, отпевши песнь и закончив молитву, подожгли несколько свечей и урну с порошком, возложили их на **тело жертвы**, дабы **все то истлело** окончательно, положили заточенный нож также **подле нее**, после чего, поклонившись, ушли, **но, как видимо не надолго,** поскольку в другой зале они тут же начали отправлять другой культ и зазывать на зрелище кого-то верховного".
[Александр Олейников. Дом №12, Выпуск 12](https://books.google.de/books?id=JuSADwAAQBAJ&pg=PT92&dq=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWjaKt68PjAhUHEVAKHRSLDV0Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82&f=false)

Именно в этом предложении:
не надолго — вместе или раздельно?
как видимо — сколько нужно запятых?

И еще (не помню точно, как называется) про "тело жертвы": все то истлело (это оно; ср. р.) и подле нее (это она; ж. р.). Что-то тут "не так". Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы зря закавычили "попалось". Употребление в таком смысле всем хорошо знакомо. С "как видимо" не знаком... Может, "как видно" имеется в виду?

Comment: Я последовала Вашему совету.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ по орфографии и пунктуации

...*после чего, поклонившись, ушли, **но (ушли), как видимо,  не надолго,**  поскольку в другой зале они тут же начали отправлять другой культ и зазывать на зрелище кого-то верховного.*

1) Для постановки знаков препинания **нужно объяснять грамматику** предложения. Я полагаю, что союз НО относится к пропущенному глаголу ***ушли***, вводное сочетание обособляется (с чего бы это союз НО соединять с  вводным оборотом?).

2) В принципе возможны **обе формы** письма: ***ненадолго*** (на короткое время) и ***не надолго*** (оценочное значение, средний вариант).  Это выбор **по семантике.**

3) Но есть еще **выбор по структуре**: при отрицании на слово обычно падает **логическое ударение**. Например:  *Он ненадолго уЕхал, но скоро вернУлся.* Здесь ожидаемой является слитная форма, так как ударением выделены однородные сказуемые.

4) В приведенном примере лучше остановиться **на раздельном написании:**  ударение падает на наречие, значение оценивается как «вряд ли надолго, не надолго».

Comment: А Вы что думаете, Sharon, по поводу "как видимо"? Так говорят? (Написал уже, что знаю только "как видно".)

Comment: До вашего вопроса, Артем,  ничего не думала, а теперь приходится. Очень уж вы наблюдательны (хорошее качество!).  Лично я в обороте ничего криминального не вижу: как видно, как видимо. Но в справочнике есть только "как видно". В Нацкорусе "как видимо" встречается, но редко. Там чаще "видимо" обособлено после КАК в сравнительном обороте. А по значению они различаются? (Да только  кто мне об этом расскажет). Можно предположить, что у "видимо" есть бОльший эффект присутствия наблюдателя в том времени, когда происходят события, чему у "видно".

Comment: Вот пример: "После смерти мужа выгнала врача, лечившего его и сиделку, так как считала их виновниками смерти мужа. Смерть, как видимо, не особенно огорчила больную, больше тревожило предстоящее материальное неблагополучие" [Т. А. Гейер. (1924)]. Я бы сказала, что форма  "как видимо" не часто употребляется, но причин на ее запрет я не вижу. Вообще говоря, эту тему можно оформить отдельным вопросом - может быть, найдутся интересные и конкретные ответы.

Comment: Спасибо большущее. Странное "как видимо" выделяется с двух сторон? Я так и предполагала. Но тогда образуется куча запятых (... подле нее, после чего, поклонившись, ушли, но, как видимо, не надолго, поскольку...), из-за которых предложение трудно воспринимается. Для чего такое скопище запятых?.. Простите, но Вы, наверно, забыли про "и еще" — про средний и женский род в "теле жертвы". Неужели все правильно?

Comment: Нет, не забыла, но это стилистика (а мой ответ по орфографии и пунктуации). Стилистика же  этого текста мне не нравится (довольно неряшливая, поэтому и запятых много),  к тому же там могут быть просто ошибки. Ну а исправлять стиль напечатанной книги - так задача вроде бы не стояла.

Comment: Отдельным вопросом? Не знаю... боюсь, что либо вопрос не привлечёт внимания вообще, либо будут отвечать новички, что у этого выражения один смысл, у того — совсем другой, и базироваться будут на своём ощущении, которое не совпадает с ощущением большинства. Конечно, подобные ответы могут оказаться не отсебятиной, а чем-то, к чему стоит прислушаться (даже и от новичка), но вероятность этого небольшая. А станут ли отвечать старожилы сайта, кроме вас (вы уже высказались), непонятно... Вон, я задал два вопроса (подряд или через один), так на них вообще никто не ответил. :(